# Display the error dialog of Google Play Service is not installed and redirect user to it

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

Hello I am trying to use the `GCM` in android application where it is require to check whether use has `Google Play Service` installed or not. For this I have coded but I don't how to handle the situation when user do not have `Google Play Service` installed.

Is there any in built a way to give prompt user to install the `Google Play Service` and redirect it to play store to install it.

```
/**
 * Check the device to make sure it has the Google Play Services APK. If
 * it doesn't, display a dialog that allows users to download the APK from
 * the Google Play Store or enable it in the device's system settings.
 */
public static boolean checkPlayServices(Context mContext) {
    int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(mContext);
    if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)) {
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, (Activity)mContext,Constants.PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

// here check whether device has google play service installed
            // if it is installed then register the device with the GCM
            // otherwise redirect user to play store to install it.

```
        if(Utils.checkPlayServices(getActivity())) {
            new RegisterGCMDeviceAsynTask(new TaskCompleteListener() {

                @Override
                public void onTaskCompleted(String result) {
                    new TeemWurkAsyncTask(new TaskCompleteListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onTaskCompleted(String result) {
                            Logger.d(TAG, result);
                        }
                    }, Constants.LOGIN_API_CALL).execute("");
                }
            }).execute();
        } else {
            // display the dialog that device do not have Google Play Service installed.

        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this :

```
if(!isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()) {
     GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(9999, this, RQS_GooglePlayServices).show();
}
```

9999 is the request code (a random integer) used in `onActivityResult()`.