# Why MapView returns null if not logged into Google Play Account?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play

I created a fragment with `MapView`, everything works fine if user is logged into Google Play Account. Then if I reset the device and launch my application, it crashes when I initialize mapView.

```
map = mapView.getMap();
```

Why would this happen? And in order to prevent the crash, should I check if user is logged into Google Account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapView.html#getMap())

> It returns the GoogleMap. ***Null if the view of the map is not yet
>   ready. This can happen when Google Play services is not available.***
>   If Google Play services becomes available afterwards, calling this
>   method again will initialize and return the GoogleMap.

And you can not access Google services until you did not logged-in to Play.

---

Although the method [GoogleMap getMap ()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapView.html#getMap()) has been deprecated, you should use [getMapAsync (OnMapReadyCallback callback)](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapView.html#getMapAsync(com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback))

Comment: Thank you. I will use `getMapAsync`, but should I ask user to log into Google Play?

Comment: Yes. At very first you should check if Play services are  ready or not. You should check any play-services-example code given by google or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23908526/display-the-error-dialog-of-google-play-service-is-not-installed-and-redirect-us.